# Function pointer delclaration in c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have written a class Seat in cpp & I declared a function pointer it it.
class implimentation is given below

Seat.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Seat.h"

int Seat::count = FL;
Seat::Seat(void)
{
   seatId = Seat::count;
   seatStatus = unoccupied;
   Seat::count++;
}

Seat::~Seat(void)
{

}


void Seat::*checkSeatStatus(void)
{


}
```

Seat.h

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

 class Seat :
    public Vehicle
{
    int seatId;
    int seatStatus;
    static int count;

public:
   Seat(void);
   ~Seat(void);
   void (*checkSeatStatus)();
};
```

it showing error at function pointer declaration :

> 'checkSeatStatus' : illegal use of type 'void'

What is the reason behind ? , does it need any initialization of function pointer ?

Comment: You declare `checkSeatStatus` as a member *variable* not a member function. As such it should be initialized to point to some callable function, but it should have no function body. What is the purpose of `checkSeatStatus`? Should it be an actual member function? Should it be a variable?

Comment: It is a member function

Comment: So it should not be a member variable, but a member function, a *method*? What should it return? A "generic pointer" (i.e. `void *`)? Nothing at all (i.e. `void`)? Return something else? What us it supposed to do?

Comment: It will find the status of the seat and set the member variable seatStatus

Comment: So it should not return any value? Then just drop the asterisk.

Comment: or better yet, have it actually return the status too.

Comment: I want to pass this function in thread. it shouldn't return a value

Comment: Oh.  :(.  Before you think about advanced stuff like threads, first you need to grok that a `Seat` is not in reality a subclass of a `Vehicle`, it is something that a vehicle "has".

Answer (score 2):

If `checkSeatStatus` is intended to be a member function it should be:

```
void* Seat::checkSeatStatus(void) {
    ...
}
```

with function prototype within the class declaration of:

```
void* checkSeatStatus(void);
```

If it's intended to be a member variable holding a function pointer that you can set then, umm, don't do that...  It's very probably the wrong design.

If (per the name) it's just supposed to return the current value of `status` then it should be a function that returns an `int` instead of a `void *`:

```
int Seat::checkStatus(void) {
    return status;
}
```

NB: I removed `Seat` from the method name since it should be implicit from the fact that you called it on a `Seat` object.

Comment: Now it showing   this error   'Seat::checkSeatStatus' : must return a value

Comment: unsurprisingly, since you've declared a function that's supposed to return a `void *` pointer.   Since you didn't say anything about what that function is supposed to do I didn't comment on that, but given that `status` is an `int` I expect your function should actually be `int Seat::checkSeatStatus(void)`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question you ask, but will show how to use the function in a thread.

Using [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) it's actually very easy to start a thread using any member function. The important part is that it should be a normal member function, so declared like

```
class Seat
{
    ...
public:
    ...
    void checkSeatStatus();
};
```

Then to create a thread using the function you first need an instance of the class:

```
Seat seat;
```

And then you simply create the thread

```
std::thread my_thread{&Seat::checkSeatStatus, seat};
```

Do whatever other processing you want to do in the main thread, and then join the thread you had created:

```
my_thread.join();
```

---

There are a couple of important things to know here: The instance of the `Seat` class (the variable `seat` above) must live longer than the thread. If it goes out of scope and is destructed before the end of the thread that will lead to *undefined behavior*.

You must also [`join`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) the tread before the thread-object (the variable `my_thread` above) is destructed.

Comment: In general, it would be `.join()` or `.detach()`, but I agree that `.detach()` doesn't work here. There's no decent way to figure out if the deteched thread is done, which means the `seat` must be kept alive indefinitely. For a joinable thread, it only has to be kept alive until the `join` returns.